# Matrix-vector notation for adding vector elements to each row of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I am adding elements from a single row vector to the respective elements in each row of a matrix.  Thus, let the $n \times 3$ matrix be

$X =\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13}\\
x_{21} & x_{22}  & x_{23}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
x_{n1} & x_{n2} & x_{n3}\\
\end{bmatrix}$,

and let the 3-element vector be

$y =\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1} & y_{2} & y_{3}\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

What would the matrix notation be for adding this vector to each row (element-by-element) of the matrix?  That is, I am doing the following:

$\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} + y_1 & x_{12} + y_2  & x_{13} + y_3 \\
x_{21}  + y_1 & x_{22} + y_2   & x_{23} + y_3 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
x_{n1}  + y_1 & x_{n2}  + y_2 & x_{n3} + y_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

What comes to mind is use of a matrix of ones, i.e. **1**, cross-multiplied by the vector, and then a simple matrix-matrix addition. Or is there a type of Kronecker addition $\oplus$ or Hadamard addition  $\boxplus$ that I could use to frontload everything?

I have seen this:

$\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{X} + \mathbf{1} \mathbf{y}^\top$

but what would the dimensions of $\mathbf{1}$ be?  If it's $n \times 3$ then the vector elements would be summed, which is not what I want.

Comment: I think $X + \mathbf{1}y^T$ is best (I'm assuming that $y$ is a column vector).

Comment: $\mathbf{1}$ would be a column vector of dimension $n$. In general, if $a$ and $b$ are column vectors of dimension $n$ and $m$ respectively, then $ab^T$ will be a matrix with $n$ rows and $m$ columns. (If $a$ and $b$ are row vectors, then you'd use $a^T b$ instead).

Comment: Yes, both of these comments are correct, since the outer product is merely $\mathbf{uv}^\top$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the outer product notation (Also as mentioned in your comments from @V.S.e.H and @eyeballfrog):

$$
\mathbf{1}\otimes\begin{pmatrix}
y_1&y_2&y_3
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\\vdots\\1
\end{pmatrix}\otimes
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1&y_2&y_3
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1&y_2&y_3\\
&\vdots\\
y_1&y_2&y_3\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
With the $\mathbf{1}$ being a vector of $1$s with length $n$. This matrix can then be added to the $X$-matrix.

Check out this wiki link for more info about the Outer product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product

Comment: I was thinking Kronecker product, and I believe that's what you are presenting(?)

Comment: I did not know it went under this name as well, but this is also stated on the wiki page.